# Почему @ManytoOne не работает, как manytoone?

Tags: java, sql, java-ee, jpa

Есть две сущности им соответствует две таблицы "Notes" и "Tags". Одному tags, может принадлежать много notes. Сделал связь "многие к одному"

```
@Entity
public class Notes {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Lob
    private String note;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tagid", nullable = false)
    public Tags tags;
```

Добавляю запись в notes

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tags tags = new Tags();
        tags.setTag("Java");
        Notes notes = new Notes();
        notes.setName("My note");
        notes.setNote("Hello World");
        notes.setTags(tags);
```

Получаем запись в таблицу notes

1 | My note | Hello world | 1

В таблице tags

1 | Java

Затем повторяем вставку и получаем в notes

1 | My note | Hello world | 1

2 | My note | Hello world | 2

А в tags

1 | Java

2 | Java

Вопрос, где тут многие к одному? Почему у меня "Java" дублируется? ведь в таблице notes должен быть в последней колонке в обоих строках 1, а в таблице Tags всегда оставаться только одна строка с "Java" - ведь в этом весь смысл связи многие к одному! Мне товарищ по python подсказал, что они при создании новой записи добавляют код "Existing or create" - вроде как "не создавай "Java" если она уже есть" Как в JPA это реализуется?

Моя проблема так решается или есть более оптимальный способ?

```
Tags tags = entityManager.createQuery("from Tags t where t.tag = :tag", Tags.class)
                .setParameter("tag", "Java")
                .getSingleResult();
        Notes notes = new Notes();
        notes.setName("test name7");
        notes.setNote("Hello Mick");
        notes.setTags(tags);
        entityManager.persist(notes);
```

Comment: Всё работает как и должно. Вы вот пишите код `new Tags();`, а это значит, что при сохранении будет создан НОВЫЙ объект Tags. Для использования существующего тега, его сначала нужно получить из персистентного хранилища. А у вас в голове какая то странная логика, вы создаёте новый объект, но ожидаете, что это не новый, а уже имеющийся. С чего бы вдруг?

Comment: @ArchDemon  Полностью согласен, просто в JPA многое делается за кулисами, и я понятия не имею где волшебство заканчивается и нужно начинать самому работать. В инете много примеров того, что сделал я, но я не смог найти, что именно нужно написать в этом простом приложении, что бы сработало классическое поведение, когда в одной таблице добавляются строки, но не заполняют однотипной записью связанную таблицу?

Comment: `em.find(Tags.class, id);` где `em` - `EntityManager `

Comment: @ArchDemon  а если я не помню id а хочу запостить заметку, зная имя тега, которому она принадлежит, будет правильно делать так, как я добавил в код к своему вопросу?

Comment: ваш код вполне годный. Почитайте про DAO, Repository в контексте ваших библиотек работы с БД

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо, за помощь. Обязательно прочитаю